# How to do the performance evaluation of findOneAndUpdate() after indexing in mongo

Tags: mongodb, query-performance

I could see .explain("executionStats") to evaluate the performance of find() queries in Mongo. But .explain is not working on findOneAndUpdate(). Is there a way to see how much the indexing is helping findOneAndUpdate() queries

Comment: Explain returns a query plan for the methods as described in this document: [db.collection.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use `.explain()` and `.findOneAndUpdate()` together. `.explain()` can be used with those functions that return cursor id, like `.find()` but it cannot be used with `.findOne()`, `.findOneAndUpdate()` and similar functions because they return a single result which is not a cursor id.

What I would suggest is to have a look at these two blog posts by Justin Liu of Rockset.

[Handling Slow Queries in MongoDB - Part 1 - Investigation](https://rockset.com/blog/handling-slow-queries-in-mongodb-part-1-investigation/)

[Handling Slow Queries in MongoDB - Part 2 - Solutions](https://rockset.com/blog/handling-slow-queries-in-mongodb-part-2-solutions/)

Answer (score 0):

in explain("executionStats"). you just remove "executionStas" and run your findOneAndUpdate query just as below

'''
db.collection.explain().findOneAndUpdate({query})
'''

it will working fine...

Comment: It did not work for me. That is the reason I asked the question.
It giving an error
E QUERY    [js] TypeError: db.mycollection.explain(...).findOneAndUpdate is not a function :

But the same thing with “update” is working though

Comment: i think 1 time 2 functions are not working you have to try stat() method. i think it is working.